# Save file to (web apps) google drive without notifying the user

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, google-drive-api

I’m writing a program that enables a user to upload a document into my projects Google drive here’s the scenario:

User A logs onto BlitzDoc. He uploads a document (using BlitzDoc’s upload page) onto BlitzDoc’s Gdrive.

Upon User A's upload she/he is presented with the following:

“BlitzDoc is requesting permission to:
•   View and manage Google Drive files that you have opened or created with this app
o   View files from Google Drive that you have opened with this app Save changes to files that you have opened with this app Create new files on Google Drive using this app
“

The thing is that BLitzDoc isn’t storing/using anything on User A’s drive (its is simply taking the uploaded Doc and storing it on BlitzDoc’s own drive account). Why then does Gdrive notify the user that this is what is happening?

Is there a way to implement the above scenario without having gdrive posting such a message? 
(I hope I was clear..)

Comment: i dont think so. this is just because of oauth.

Comment: I agree with Daniel. Access to any gdrive API requires a google account, and since it is the user's data being uploaded I am not surprised they are offered an opportunity to cancel the operation.

Comment: but its the users data from his file-system. not from his google drive..is there a way for me to let him/her upload to BLitzDoc gdrive by some other means?

Comment: Would you need to know the user when uploading? Did the user identify itself in another way to your app? If so, create a generic account and use that to upload. If you need it to be specific to the user, you're stuck with the OAuth message.

Comment: yeah they identify themselves via our own authentication process...can u suggest how i would set up a generic account? im not sure i understand..